# External Installer has stopped working

Tags: visual-studio-2010, servicepacks

I have Visual Studio 2010 Professional on my machine. I am trying to install Service pack 1 for VS 2010 but getting error "**External Installer has stopped working**". Earlier I have installed the same copy of service pack on my desktop and it worked like charm. But when I am trying to install it on my laptop, I am not able to. I am NOT using online installer, I have offline version of service pack which has worked fine before. Can anyone help me out?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restart your computer and problem will be solved.

Hope it helps.